# Select statement into another select To Eloquant

Tags: mysql, sql, eloquent

How can I translate a SQL query like this to Eloquent or QueryBuilder :

```
SELECT * FROM studies
where studies.id in(SELECT study_id FROM (
SELECT max(studies.end_date), studies.id as study_id
from  workers inner join resumes on workers.id=resumes.worker_id
inner join studies on resumes.id=studies.resume_id where
resumes.title="main" group by workers.id) as SQ2
```

Or globally

How can we make select from other select statement with eloquant for exemple:

```
SELECT a.id from (SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON a.id=b.id where a.id > 10) as SUBQ1
```

Comment: why you return max(end_date) in your nested query?

Comment: I wanna get just last formation of each worker,
and a worker may have several formations.
so, I try to select just the last.

Answer (score 0):

I think your current query doesn't get study_id with max end_date in all cases, you can try this one:

> ```
> SELECT * FROM studies
> where studies.end_date in (
> SELECT max(studies.end_date)
> from  workers inner join resumes on workers.id=resumes.worker_id
> inner join studies on resumes.id=studies.resume_id where
> resumes.title="main" group by workers.id)
> ```

and if you want implement that with laravel Eloquant you can do it like this:

> ```
> $result = DB::table('studies')
>     ->select("*")
>     ->whereIn('end_date', function($query){
>     $query->selectRaw("max(studies.end_date) as max_date")
>     ->from('workers')
>     ->join('resumes', 'workers.id', '=', 'resumes.worker_id')
>     ->join('studies', 'resumes.id', '=', 'studies.resume_id')
>     ->where('resumes.title', '=', 'main')
>     ->groupBy('workers.id');
>     })
>     ->get();
> ```

```
foreach($result as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
```

Comment: It works for me with Sql syntex but, with eloquent, I did not find a solution for select into antoher select statement.
Globaly, my question it's how to make a select from result of another select like that:
Select A FROM (Select C.A,MAX(C.PRICE) FROM products) as Q2